# Create an iframe then append data to it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, userscripts

I am trying do some modification to an greasemonkey userscript to implement a feature I need. The code is like

```
showAddress:function(addrString,type)
{
        this.addrBox=$('<div id="batchPublish"></div>')
        .append('<div id="batchHeader"></div>')
        .append('<div id="batchContent" style="float:left;clear:both"></div>');

   .........

 var batchContent=this.addrBox.find('#batchContent')
        .append('<pre width="300" style="text-align:left" id="batchedlink"></pre>'); 

         this.addrBox.find('#batchedlink').css({'width':'500px','height':'250px','overflow':'auto','word-wrap': 'break-word'})
        .append(addrString); 

        $.blockUI({message:this.addrBox,css:{width:"520px",height:"300px"}}); }
```

Basically this code writes data to html. What I want to implement is to have "addrString" written to an iframe embedded. Now It's in the "pre" tag. I have tried many approaches but still no luck. Iframe was always empty. 
I am completely a novice in javascript and unclear whether this is possible.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are adding the iFrame in the same domain, then you can manipulate its contents like this:
([**See it in action at jsBin.**](http://jsbin.com/ahoqav/edit#preview))

```
$("#batchContent").append ('<iframe id="batchedlink"></iframe>');

/*--- Compensate for a bug in IE and FF, Dynamically added iFrame needs 
    some time to become "DOM-able".
*/
setTimeout ( function () {
        var iframeBody  = $("#batchedlink").contents ().find ("body");

        iframeBody.append (addrString);
    },
    333
);
```

**NOTE:**
For a Chrome userscript, you apparently don't need the timer delay.  But for FF and IE 8 (the other 2 browsers I double-checked), a *dynamically* added iFrame is not manipulable until after it has "settled" for some reason.  This *seems* to take about 200 mS.

A statically loaded iFrame does not have this lag, see the jsBin demo.

Comment: OMG, this is the hackyist ******* ******** of my life, but thank you for your answer !! +1

Answer (score 0):

Sort of hard to tell exactly what you're asking -- but if you want to know whether or not you can append DOM elements to an iFrame, the answer is "no".