# How to get content of a modal using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

How can i get content of a button using jquery from a webpage? the button opens up a modal. I am displaying this content in another modal.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("iframe").load("someUrl #someId",function(response) {

    });
  });
});
```

the modal is as follows

```
<div id="test">
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal4">Table 2</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal4" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 15px; width: 100%; text-align: left; ">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Hello </td>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th> </th>
                        <td>world </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to get the content of the *modal*, not the *button* - is that right? If so, unless the content of the modal is in the HTML which is loaded initially then you will not be able to do this. This is also assuming you're not making a cross domain AJAX call, which will likely be blocked by CORS anyway

Comment: Both applications are running locally on my PC so CORS is already taken of.And yes I want to get the content of the modal. Is actually a table in the modal

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("iframe").load("someUrl #someId",function(response) {
        $('#firstDiv').dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Confirmation",
        open: function() {
          var markup = 'Hello World';
          $(this).html(response);
        },
        buttons: {
          Ok: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        }
      });  //end confirm dialog
    });
  });
});
```

I hope, you are using the Jquery modal. Else you can set content by dynamically.

Comment: I just modified the question with the content of the modal. I want to get the table from this modal in my second application.Also i just tried using the code as you mentioned but gives me an error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function"

Comment: You need to include jquery-ui js.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369302/how-to-get-element-by-id-from-another-website) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394438/create-an-iframe-then-append-data-to-it-with-jquery) answers on SO, I was able to archive what i wanted. perhaps, it could help someone

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('remoteUrl').then(function (html) {
        // Success response
        var $mainbar = $(html).find('#ID_of_Your_Remote_Modal');
        $("#iframe").append ('<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>');

        setTimeout ( function () {
                var iframeBody  = $("#iframe").contents().find("body");

                iframeBody.append ($mainbar);
            },
            333
        );
    }, function () {
        // Error response
        document.write('Access denied');
        });
    });

</script>
```